# Provide SSL certificate to PostgreSQL in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Rails app on Elastic Beanstalk using an Amazon RDS PostgreSQL instance.

I'd like pg to use SSL to connect to this DB.

Following [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/[...]](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL), I saved [rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem](http://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem) at `/config/ca/rds.pem` and my `database.yml` looks like this:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_ADDRESS'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DB_PORT'] %>
  sslmode: 'require'
  sslrootcert: 'config/ca/rds.pem'
```

But I have no idea if it's really using SSL: I can change `sslrootcert` path to anything, and my app is still up. What am I missing?

Comment: I see that you are pointing to pem file, and I also see some articles referring to file of extension `crt` (like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355047/pg-gem-sslmode-verify-full-where-to-place-certificates?rq=1 ) , what's the difference between them? did they both work for you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `database.yml` you have to use `sslmode: 'verify-full'` instead of `sslmode: 'require'` in order to verify the instance endpoint against the endpoint in the SSL certificate. This way the certificate is used.