# pg gem sslmode=verify-full, where to place certificates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.1

Is there a way for the pg-gem to use sslmode = verify-full for it's postgres connection? Would that be as simple as just passing that string in? I have a Rails app that I want to do full ca protected ssl connections on to an external db and I don't really know how to setup the ca part of that. Using require on sslmode defaults it to use ssl traffic but I don't know where (or under what user, etc.) I should be placing my certificates to do verification. Should I just place them under ~/.postgresql/ like in the normal psql client workflow for verified ssl certs with the names root.crt and postgresql.cert and postgresql.key?

I'm using Postgres 9.1 if that helps at all.

EDIT FOR THOSE WHO COME LATER:

The following database.yml file seems to work as a test on my dev machine. I'll be writing a blog post on this issue for sure since it was such a PITA to figure out what was going wrong.

```
  host: 127.0.0.1
  sslcert: <%= Rails.root.join('config', 'client.crt') %>
  sslkey: <%= Rails.root.join('config', 'client.key') %>
  sslrootcert: <%= Rails.root.join('config', 'root.crt') %>
  sslmode: verify-full
  database: pg-test_development
  username: postgres
  password:
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Pg` gem uses `libpq` internally, the same client library as the PostgreSQL tools like `psql`.

By default `libpq` looks in `~/.postgresql/` for the CA certificate.

From [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-ssl.html):

> To allow server certificate verification, the certificate(s) of one or more trusted CAs must be placed in the file `~/.postgresql/root.crt` in the user's home directory. (On Microsoft Windows the file is named `%APPDATA%\postgresql\root.crt`.)

... and ...

> The location of the root certificate file and the CRL can be changed by setting the connection parameters `sslrootcert` and `sslcrl` [...]

AFAIK Rails passes anything you put in your `database.yml` to the `Pg` gem, which passes it to `libpq` as a connection parameter. So you should be able to add key/value entries to your `database.yml` stanzas like:

```
sslmode: verify-full
# and if you don't want to use ~/.postgresq/root.crt for the cert location, set:
sslrootcert: /path/to/my/app/root/cert.crt
```

---

IMO the requirement to pass a single root cert to `libpq` is a design flaw. It should load a trusted certificate database. Similar issues exist for use of SSL client certificates, where you can't supply a keystore and cert store, you must pass specific files for a given host. It sounds like that's probably OK for you since you know the upstream certificate signing authority.

Comment: Sick! Thanks man. Is there any way to configure the location of the postgresql.crt and key file too? In the man pages it states that they should be in the clients /.postgresql dir as well but I'm not sure if I can move that location around to somewhere rails can easily access. I was only able to get secure connections to work with those key and crt files in place on my client, which in this case was just testing on local host.

Comment: After checking the manual it seems I can place my signed cert and key in my rails app for my client anywhere and modify the location in boot with sslcert and sslkey in the yml file just like doing the server verification. I'll try it out today and see if that works.thanks so much man!